# How to name the constraint when add NOT NULL on ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl, notnull

`ALTER TABLE ACTOR MODIFY FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL;`

I know have to set `FIST_NAME` to `NOT NULL`, but I don not know how to name this constraint.

The name of this constraint should be "CK_Fanme"

Comment: I mean I don not know how to name it at the same time.  For example:`ALTER TABLE LANGUAGE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LANGUAGEID PRIMARY KEY (LANGUAGE_ID);`, in this statement we can name it as `PK_LANGUAGEID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
ALTER TABLE actor MODIFY ( first_name CONSTRAINT not_null_first_name NOT NULL );
```

and query to see the result through use of `user_constraints` data dictionary view such as

```sql
SELECT constraint_name
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'ACTOR'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1575b6a209f005dab0a47b691f860a9)</kbd>